# Insertar detalle de pedido en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Buenas noches estoy trabajando con laravel 5.4
el problema es que tengo dos tablas un Pedido y detalle de pedido hice un carrito de compras esta todo bien con session  a lo que voy es que cuando quiero insertar a la tabla pedido y detalle de pedido no inserta. dejo el codigo ahi,
cualquier aporte es bienvenido gracias de antemano.
pd:estoy con mysql

esto es el controlador:

```
public function postgrabardetalle(Request $request)
{



    try {
            DB::beginTransaction();
            $pedido=new Pedido;
            $pedido->cod_cliente=$request->get('cod_cliente');
            $mytime=Carbon::now('America/Lima');
            $pedido->fecha=$mytime->todateTimeString();
            $pedido->igv='18';

            $pedido->cod_empleado=1;
            $pedido->estado='1'; 
            $pedido->save();

            $detpedido=new DetallePedido;


            $cod_producto=$request->input('cod_producto');
            $cantidad=$request->input('cantidad');
            $precioventa=$request->input('precioventa');
            $importe=$request->input('importe');

            //$cart=new Carro($oldCart);
           $contador=0;
           while ($contador < count($cod_producto)) {            
                $detpedido->cod_pedido=$pedido->cod_pedido;
                $detpedido->cod_producto=$cod_producto[$contador];
                $detpedido->cantidad=$cantidad[$contador];
                $detpedido->precioventa=$precioventa[$contador];
                $detpedido->importe=$importe[$contador];                
                $detpedido->save();
                $contador=$contador+1;
            }

            DB::commit();

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();
        }
        Session::forget('carro');
     return Redirect::to('/carro')->with('success','pedido agregado correctamente');  
     //return $cod_producto;  


}
```

esto es la vista

```
-----------------------------------
@extends('layouts.inicio')

@section('content')

  @if(Session::has('carro'))
<form action="{{route('grabardetalle')}}" method="POST">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">
        <label for="cliente">Clientes</label>
        <select name="cod_cliente" id="" class="form-control selectpicker" data-Live-search="true">
          @foreach($clientes as $cli)
          <option value="{{$cli->cod_cliente}}">{{$cli->nombre}}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">
        <h3 class="col-sm-offset-4">Detalle de Pedido</h3>
        <br>
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="info">Descripcion</th>
              <th class="info">Cantidad</th>
              <th class="info">Precio</th>
              <th class="info">Importe</th>
              <th class="info">Acciones</th>

            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            @foreach((array)$producto as $pro)

            <tr >
              <td style=""><input type="hidden" name="cod_producto[]" value="{{$pro['item']['cod_producto']}}"  disabled=""> {{$pro['item']['descripcion']}} </td>
              <td> <input type="text" name="cantidad[]" value="{{$pro['cant']}}" disabled="" > </td>
              <td><input type="text" name="precioventa[]" value="{{$pro['precioventa']}}" disabled="" > </td>
              <td><input type="text" name="importe[]" value="{{$pro['importe']}}" disabled=""> </td>

              <td width="50"  ><a href="{{ route('carro.reducituno', ['id' => $pro['item']['cod_producto']])}}"  type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Elimnar 1</a>
                         <a href="{{ route('carro.removeItem', ['id' => $pro['item']['cod_producto']])}}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Limpiar</a></td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">
        <h3>Total: S/. <input type="text" name="" value="{{$subtotal}}"  disabled=""> </h3> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="">Grabar</button>
         <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" name="">Cancelar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
  @else
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
      <h2>No Hay Productos Agregados</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  @endif

@endsection
```

Comment: Hola, has comprobado lo siguiente: Llegas hasta el controlador? Llegas hasta el bucle? En caso de llegar hasta el bucle, los datos que asignas son correctos? Has probado a imprimirlos a ver qué llega?

Comment: no llega hasta al bucle por que no logro recuperar el codigo del producto que estan en la tabla de la vista

Comment: Podrías comprobar la petición con las herramientras de desarollo de firefox? Carga tu página y rellena el formulario, después, abre las herramientas con control+shift+k y después ves al apartado de "Red". Ahora submite el formulario. Debería verse una petición POST. Si te pones encima deberías ver los paráemtros que se envían. Se están enviando los datos que esperas?